# getMenuInflater causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

Longpressing on android app to bring up context menu causes null point exception crash. Any and all help appreciated, let me know if more code may be needed, I'm not sure what else may be useful. Thanks.

```
    mTitleEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (mTitleEditText != null) {
                    Log.d("mTitleEditText", " " + mTitleEditText.getText().toString());
                    SpellingsClient.myFunction(mTitleEditText);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

//This is how editText is passed into my class. The class runs perfectly except for bringing up this menu, so I don't think the issue is here.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.d("Tester", " menu " + menu + " v " + v + " menuInfo " + menuInfo + "  getMenuInflater() " +  getMenuInflater());
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_contextual_menu, menu);

        /*This adjusts menu items depending on if the word is inside of the personal dictionary*/
        if (itsInDict) {
            addOrRemove = "Remove from Dictionary";
        } else {
            addOrRemove = "Add to Dictionary";
        }

        /*These add in the menu items*/
        if (!itsInArray) {
            menu.add(0, 1, 1, addOrRemove);
        }
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, firstSuggestedWord);
        if (!originalWordTyped.equals("")) {
            menu.add(0, 3, 2, "Revert to: " + originalWordTyped);
        }
    }
```

//This is where the error is (getMenuInflator() is causing the crash)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ws.xsoh.etar, PID: 14389
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:3303)
        at android.app.Activity.getMenuInflater(Activity.java:4917)
        at com.android.calendar.SpellingsClient.onCreateContextMenu(SpellingsClient.java:426)
        at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:14263)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.showPopup(ContextMenuBuilder.java:102)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.showContextMenuForChildInternal(DecorView.java:837)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(DecorView.java:814)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:971)
        at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:7295)
        at android.widget.TextView.showContextMenu(TextView.java:10930)
        at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:7209)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7163)
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12177)
        at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:7181)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:27259)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling from a Fragment, directly from an Activity or some other class?

If not from an activity, but from a fragment, try this instead:

`MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();`

Comment: It's from another class that I'm calling it. I've already tried that solution before and it doesn't work - it makes me import android.app.pendingintent.getactivity and then, after importing it, says cannot resolve method getActivity(). This is the class: 
public class EditEventView implements View.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnCancelListener,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener,
        RecurrencePickerDialog.OnRecurrenceSetListener,
        TimeZonePickerDialog.OnTimeZoneSetListener {

Comment: You could either pass your activity to the class (ideally as weakreference, if the class could outlive the activity, so it does not interfere with garbage collection), or get the context of the view with view.getContext(), and then get the menuinflater from that context.

Comment: Do you mean like this, for your second suggestion, ?   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        v.getContext();
        MenuInflater menuInflater = v.getMenuInflater(); //It says it can't resolve getMenuInflator.

Comment: @contaminate if you could cast the context to Activity, but you should have a fallback in case the view is not attached to activity but to another type of context.

Comment: Can you give an example in code or pseudocode? I'm not sure I'm understanding. Thank you for your replies!